# Confused over Java versions

Tags: java

Can anyone give me a quick answer. I've been tasked with finding out the features of J2SE 1.2 but when I do a search on the internet it always gives me JDK 1.2. Are these the same?

Comment: Why, for heavens sake? B.t.w., J2SE is the Java platform, and the JDK is the Development Kit: the functionality that is in the platform, is also in the Development Kit, of course. So I think they can be interchanged, in your case.

Comment: Grammatical question: I'm Dutch speaking. Shouldn't it be "Confused about" ?

Comment: But why do you need to research a Java version that is almost 13 years old (in December)?

Answer (score 5):

Yes they are the same. J2SE means "Java 2 Standard Edition". It was the "marketing" name for the version 1.2. JDK means "Java Development Kit".

I hope you're doing this only for archeological reasons, because this version is obsolete for quite a long time.

Comment: It's for a version report I need to do. Thanks for your help.

Comment: J2SE was used for Java 1.2 upto Java 5, so the term J2SE is not a one-to-one related to Java 1.2.

Answer (score 2):

Java 2 Standard Edition (J2SE) version 1.2 and the JDK 1.2 is the Java Development Kit that confoms to the design of the J2SE 1.2 specifications.

Answer (score 2):

This page has a complete list of java version names http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history  None of the current versions use the name `J2SE`, instead they are called `Java SE`